# Retrieving Data from AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to retrieve data from Angularfire using a service, and then setting the returned value to my scope in my controller.

When I run the code below, I get undefined back for scope.sessions.

SERVICE:

```
app.factory('sessions', function(){

var refToSessions = new Firebase('myFireBaseURL');
var allSessions = [];

return {
getSessions: function () {
  refToSessions.on("value", function (sessions) {
    allSessions.push(sessions.val());
    return allSessions;
  });
}
```

};
});

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller('SessionsCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Auth', 'sessions', function($scope, $state, Auth, sessions){
  $scope.sessions = sessions.getSessions();

$scope.submitSession = function() {
console.log($scope.sessions);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to return asynchronous data.

You are logging `allSessions` to the console before the data has downloaded from Firebase.

Use `$firebaseArray` from [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html).

```
app.constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-url>');
app.service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase);
app.factory('Sessions', function(rootRef, $firebaseArray){
  var refToSessions = ref.child('sessions');
  return $firebaseArray('sessions');
}
```

Then injection `Sessions` into your controller:

```
app.controller('SessionsCtrl', function($scope, $state, Auth, Sessions){
  $scope.sessions = Sessions; // starts downloading the data

  console.log($scope.sessions); // still empty

  $scope.submitSession = function() { 
    // likely by the time you click here it will be downloaded
    console.log($scope.sessions);
    $scope.sessions.$add({ title: 'new session' });
  };
});
```

The data starts downloading once it's injected into your controller. When it's downloaded, `$firebaseArray` knows to trigger `$digest`, so it appears on the page.

Since you're using `ui-router`, you can use `resolve` to make sure the data exists before injecting it into your controller:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state("session", {
      controller: "SessionsCtrl",
      templateUrl: "views/sessions.html",
      resolve: {
        sessions: function(Sessions) {
          // return a promise that will fulfill the data
          return Sessions.$loaded(); 
        }
      }
    })
});
```

Now you would change your controller code to this:

```
app.controller('SessionsCtrl', function($scope, $state, Auth, sessions){
  $scope.sessions = sessions; // data is available since injected by router

  console.log($scope.sessions); // logs the appropriate data

  $scope.submitSession = function() { 
    $scope.sessions.$add({ title: 'new session' });
  };
});
```